# Alternatives to CLI and SNMP

Tags: network-programming, snmp, cisco, switching, alternate

I am trying to write a small script that will help me automate some of my IT tasks regarding to VLAN management.
I do not want to log-in to my switch via command-line - I want to send commands to it and get response (over the NET).
Are there any alternatives? I have started to search the web but so far I did not found anything. 
I know SNMP is an option to gain info but I want to check other alternatives 
thanks.

Comment: Quick and dirty: script ssh access and the commands you execute in bash. Oxidized uses this approach to backup and restore switch configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Netconf Configuration Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NETCONF), it is RPC-like management protocol which is supported by Cisco and many other vendors.

Comment: In SDN area at least, several vendors now offering NETCONF interfaces in addition to traditional CLI/SNMP interfaces. Interesting article at http://jedelman.com/home/netconf-and-the-ncclient/

Answer (score 0):

**SNMP** is the only widely and commonly used option here.

1. You can use **WMI** to manage Windows-based infrastructure.
2. There is also legacy **SYSLOG** protocol (`RFC3164`) which is UDP based.
3. For traffic monitoring and billing purposes there are **NetFlow**,
   **sFlow**, **jFlow**, **IPFIX** and **RADIUS** protocols.
4. There are some other protocols but mostly proprietary.

So I'd suggest using **SNMP** which is nowadays a de-facto standard in network monitoring domain.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at Expect as a scripting language solution.  It is commonly used to do exactly what you are needing:

- log into device (with result cases)
- execute commands
- save config
- logout

As you build out a script library, tasks become simplified as you could do things like run scripts with parameters and have Expect do all the detail work.

See the wikipedia article for an overview.

I have also used SNMP for this kind of thing but the functionality is different because you are using an SNMP read-write privilege to upload new parts or complete configs, saving the running config to flash and/or saving the config off-device.

Answer (score 0):

Try NETCONF+YANG protocol because it is currently the best option for network device configuration. More about SNMP alternatives:
https://bestmonitoringtools.com/top-snmp-alternatives-because-snmp-is-dying/